# Flowplayer changing all icons colors

Tags: html, css, flowplayer

Hello so recently I've purchased flowplayer and I've received their CSS file that contains some gray theme, what I am trying to do is to change color of the player buttons to white but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

Sample code

```
<div class='flowplayer' title="Test 123" data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-key='' data-ratio='0.4167'>
  <video> <source type='video/mp4' src='local://video.mp4'> </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out their docs here: https://flowplayer.com/docs/player/skinning#brand-colors

You can use the `.fp-color` class as so:

```css
.flowplayer .fp-color {
  background-color: #373484;
}
```

Depending on your use case, you could also change the `color` attribute of the `.flowplayer .fp-ui` class.